# How to load ul from localStorage (todo app)?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, html-lists

I've created a classic todo app in vanilla js, to practice some things, one of those being saving and loading to/from localStorage.

I seem to make the app save to localStorage but not loading from it when refreshing the page.

I don't store everything in an array, but a ul with items in separate li's.

Would love to get some thoughts on how to make it work.

Code is below.

Here's a link to jsfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Jossif/udx27ye8/

````
const list = document.querySelector('.todo__list');
const undone = document.querySelector('.todo__list__undone');
const done = document.querySelector('.todo__list__done');

const newItem = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = document.querySelector('.todo__register__input').value;
  if (text === '') {
    return;
  }
  addItem(text);
  document.querySelector('.todo__register__input').value = '';
};

const addItem = text => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = text;
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  removeBtn.classList.add('remove__btn');
  removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';
  li.appendChild(removeBtn);
  undone.appendChild(li);
  saveItem();
};

undone.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    event.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    done.appendChild(event.target);
    saveItem();
  }
});

done.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    event.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    undone.appendChild(event.target);
    saveItem();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.target.classList.contains('remove__btn')) {
    event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
  saveItem();
});

const saveItem = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('list', list.innerHTML);
};

const loadStorage = () => {
  const data = localStorage.getItem('list');
  list.innerHTML = data;
};

btn.addEventListener('click', newItem);```


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Jossif/udx27ye8/
````

Comment: Hey, i don't seem to see you ever call the `loadStorage` method?

Comment: Oh true, I had it just above the event listener for click, but it didn't work so I removed it before I posted here.

What happened then was that I couldn't add things to the list or anything

Answer (score 0):

you should maintain todolist as an array globally

```
let todo_list=[]
```

now you add item should push newly added item to todo_list like

```
 const addItem = text => {
   const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = text;
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    removeBtn.classList.add('remove__btn');
    removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';
    li.appendChild(removeBtn);
    undone.appendChild(li);
    todo_list.push({text:text,stats:0});//add it to list
    saveItem();
};
```

now you save item should write it as an json string to local storage instead of html element like:

```
localStorage.setItem('list',JSON.stringify(todo_list));
```

now remove should remove from todo_list and make call to save,and same for status change of list item.

inorder to load from local storage you should load them on document ready as:

```
todo_list=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list');
 if(todo_list.length > 0){
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
           let item=todo_list[i];
           const li = document.createElement('li');
           li.innerHTML = item.text;
           const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
           removeBtn.classList.add('remove__btn');
           removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';
           li.appendChild(removeBtn);
           if(item.status){
             li.classList.add("checked");//your class to make it check
           }
      }
  }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it out and it seems to store to storage but not showing the items on the page when I refresh the page.

I'm posting a comment below with how the loadStorage function looks like now

Comment: `const loadStorage = () => {
  todo_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));
  if (todo_list.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < todo_list.length; i++) {
      let item = todo_list[i];
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = item.text;
      const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
      removeBtn.classList.add('remove__btn');
      removeBtn.innterHTML = 'X';
      li.appendChild(removeBtn);
      if (item.status) {
        list.classList.add('checked');
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: Sorry if it looks wierd but I can't post longer comments..
I added this piece to show the items but it show's everything as undone (even though I marked them), and it also doesn't show the remove btn.

`if (item.status) {
        list.classList.add('checked');
        done.appendChild(li);
        return;
      }
      undone.appendChild(li);
    }`